# Can be create constructor doble in a php class?

Tags: php, html, file, class, dto

im work with php and mysql, sometimes i need instantiate my php class in data access layer for return objects, load list etc... but sometimes I use the class constructor and others do not.

Can i create doble constructor in a class?

example:

```
class Student {

private $id;
private $name;
private $course;

function __construct() {

}

//get set id and name

function setCourse($course) {
    $this->course = $course;
}


function getCourse() {
    $this->course = $course;
}

}

class Course {

private $id;
private $description;

function __construct($id) {
   this->id = $id;
}

//get set, id, description

}
```

In my access layer sometime I use the constructor in different ways
   for example:

```
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $listStudent = new ArrayObject();

        if($result != null) {

            foreach($result as $row) {

                $student = new Student();

                $student->setId($row['id']);
                $student->setName($row['name']);
                $student->setCourse(new Course($row['idcourse'])); //this works

                $listStudent ->append($sol);
            }
            }
```

But sometimes I need to use the constructor in another way, for example

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $listCourses = new ArrayObject();

        if($result != null) {

            foreach($result as $row) {

                $course = new Course();  //but here not work, becouse Class course receives a id

                $course->setId($row['idcourse']);
                $course->setDescription($row['description']);

                $listCourses->append($sol);
            }
        }
```

My english is very bad, 
i hope you understand me

Comment: Your English is good, however I don't understand what do you want to achieve. Do you want to create a class with two (or more) constructors?

Comment: The purpose of a constructor is to initialize the object's properties, to make it ready to be used. Empty constructors (+ setters) as it happens in class `Student` are a sign of procedural programming disguised as OOP. Put the initialization of `Student` properties in its constructor and remove the setters.

Comment: Hi, i want to achieve is to be create objects with constructor and without constructor, without cause errors... for example:

$course = new Course();  --> works
 and
$course = new Course($id); --> also works

but as i have ir not work:

$course = new Course();  --> not work
 and
$course = new Course($id); --> works

thanks for your time

Comment: There is no such thing as "object without constructor". An object with properties without a constructor or with an empty constructor is just a dull data structure that can contain anything. OOP is about encapsulation (of the data) and behaviour. The classes `Student` and `Course` posted in your question are a waste of time and resources, not OOP. You can use arrays instead with the same results (and less code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [default arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

```php
class Course {

  private $id;
  private $description;

  function __construct($id = 0) {
    this->id = $id;
  }

  // getters and setters for id and description

}
```

Now, you can use it like that:

```php
$course = new Course(12); // works with argument
```

or:

```php
$course = new Course(); // works without argument
$course->setId(12);
```

Comment: Ok, but my idea is reduce code in some functions, por example:

https://paste2.org/kbt56aBW

Comment: So in some cases, you don't want to call the constructor at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Course {

    private $id;
    private $description;

    public function __construct() {
            // allocate your stuff
        }

    public static function constructWithID( $id ) {
            $instance = new self();
            //do your stuffs here
            return $instance;
        }
```

call like Course:: constructWithID(..id) when you have to pass id otherwise make object (new Course()).

Comment: The static method `constructWitID()` is also known as "named constructor". It is not a bad (or good) practice *per se*. The way you use it (and the regular constructor) to create new objects is the part that can be classified as good or bad practice.